# Changing the username command in terminal in Mac

Tags: python, terminal

I am using terminal to try to run my code and I got it to run yesterday, but the username was `tests-MacBook-Pro-2:sunkunoil maryjacketti$` and today it is `tests-MacBook-Pro-2:~ maryjacketti$` and it won't run the code. The code is inside the folder `sunkunoil` on my computer. How do I get the terminal to say prompt the command like yesterday?

Comment: if you mean to switch the users, you have to use $ su -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac, the paths are at different locations. For posterity, you can either change to a **relative path**

```
cd SOSim/sunkunoil
```

or an **absolute path**

```
cd /Users/maryjacketti/SOSim/sunkunoil
```

The first part is where you start out when you start the Terminal app. It is also called you *HOME directory*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the directory that you are working in. This isn't an issue with the user that you are using, but rather where you are in the file system.

```
cd /desktop/sosim/sunkunoil
python [what ever your program name is]
```

The structure of terminal is:

```
[machine]: [current folder] [user]$
```

You are currently in home which is represented by ~.

Comment: when i type cd sunkunoil into the terminal it tells me there is no such file or directory

Comment: Where is sunkunoil located on your mac? @Mary

Comment: on my desktop in a folder called SOSim

Comment: @mary edited it to reflect this. Tell me if it works.

Comment: it is still telling me that there is no such file or directory

Comment: Just do `ls`. Then `cd` until you find the top most folder of the project and keep `cd`ing until you get to the directory that it is in.